# Problem with AuthzSVNAccessFile

Tags: svn, apache, authentication

I have installed Apache and Subversion on Windows. My config is:

```
<Location /svn>
    DAV svn
    SVNListParentPath on
    SVNParentPath "d:\svn"
    AuthzSVNAccessFile "d:\svn\svnaccess.conf"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Subversion repository"
    AuthUserFile "D:\svn\svn-auth-file"
    Require valid-user 
</Location>
```

and my svnaccess.conf is:

```
[/]
* = r
```

If i take off or comment the line:

```
    AuthzSVNAccessFile "d:\svn\svnaccess.conf"
```

from apache everything works and I can log in with my user, but if i put the line back on it gives a connection reset error when I try access from browser (Google Chrome, Firefox or IE):

```
Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): Unknown error.
```

Anyone have a clue about why my AuthSVNAccessFile is not working?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anything in your Apache error logs?

Comment: Nothing... only notices...
<pre>
[Wed Apr 07 12:01:33 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Win32) SVN/1.6.6 DAV/2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Apr 07 12:01:33 2010] [notice] Server built: Mar  4 2010 11:27:46
[Wed Apr 07 12:01:33 2010] [notice] Parent: Created child process 1704
[Wed Apr 07 12:01:33 2010] [notice] Child 1704: Child process is running
[Wed Apr 07 12:01:33 2010] [notice] Child 1704: Acquired the start mutex.
[Wed Apr 07 12:01:33 2010] [notice] Child 1704: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Apr 07 12:01:33 2010] [notice] Child 1704: Starting thread to ...
</pre>

Comment: What modules are you loading?  It should be something like this:

LoadModule ldap_module   modules/mod_ldap.so
LoadModule authnz_ldap_module   modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module   modules/mod_authz_svn.so

Comment: I created an answer with all modules being loaded and the commented ones...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally made it! The problem was the order of the loading modules in Apache conf file.
I added the SVN required modules in the end of modules loading section and now it is working fine!!!

Now it looks like:

```
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
#LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
#LoadModule authn_alias_module modules/mod_authn_alias.so
#LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
#LoadModule authn_dbd_module modules/mod_authn_dbd.so
#LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
LoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_default.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
#LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
#LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
#LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
#LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
#LoadModule cern_meta_module modules/mod_cern_meta.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
#LoadModule charset_lite_module modules/mod_charset_lite.so

#LoadModule dav_lock_module modules/mod_dav_lock.so
#LoadModule dbd_module modules/mod_dbd.so
#LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
#LoadModule disk_cache_module modules/mod_disk_cache.so
#LoadModule dumpio_module modules/mod_dumpio.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
#LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
#LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
#LoadModule file_cache_module modules/mod_file_cache.so
#LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
#LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
#LoadModule ident_module modules/mod_ident.so
#LoadModule imagemap_module modules/mod_imagemap.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
#LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
#LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
#LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
#LoadModule log_forensic_module modules/mod_log_forensic.so
#LoadModule mem_cache_module modules/mod_mem_cache.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
#LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
#LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
#LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
#LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
#LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
#LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
#LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
#LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
#LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
#LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
#LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
#LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
#LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
#LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
#LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
#LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
#LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so

LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so

LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule dav_svn_module modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module modules/mod_authz_svn.so
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your problem it's also worth ensuring that the authz_svn module is loaded *after* the dav_svn module.

Refer to the [Bitnami forum for more details](http://answers.bitnami.org/questions/6431).